# Stumbled upon a puzzling issue, I'm unable to make a carousel image lead to an address in href via touch on a mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-handling, carousel

So this is my first time ever posting on stackoverflow, Usually I'm simply scouring for an answer I need , however this time after long time of searching for solutions and trying out different solutions, I've decided to try and ask  some of the smart people on stackoverflow , I'm simply unable to make an image inside of a carousel to be clickable and lead to an address inside of its "href" link , on any computer this works correctly, however on the mobile phone it's just not .
I'm stumped i don't know if its related to an touch event handler+touchfingerpress event , or to it being inside of a carousel div overlapping, tried clearfix class, tried, different solutions, so far no luck lol.
this is the entire code with placeholder links for images and the rest, but you can see the mechanism none the less in this live w3space fiddle  : https://menk-s-space.w3spaces.com/carousel.html
or the entire link in plain:
thanks for the helpers. I would love to learn and improve!

```
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="bootstrap-iso clearfix">
<div id="slider9" class="slider9 clearfix">
<div id="slide9r" class="slide9r clearfix d-flex aligns-items-center justify-content-center" >
  <div class="wrapper9 clearfix" >
    <div id="slide9s" class="slide9s clearfix" >
        
      <span class="slide9 clearfix" >   
          
      <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="portfolio.php">
    <img src="portfolio/portfolio1.png" alt="Cinque Terre">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">portfolio0</div>
  <div class="portfolio-item-meta clearfix">
                           <h5><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio0</a></h5>
                     <p>PC solutions</p>
                        </div>
</div>


        
                    
              
            </span>
      <span class="slide9 clearfix">  
      <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="portfolio1.php">
    <img src="portfolio/portfolio2.png" alt="Forest" >
  </a>
  <div class="desc">portfolio1</div>
  <div class="portfolio-item-meta clearfix">
                           <h5><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio1</a></h5>
                     <p>PC solutions</p>
                        </div>
</div>


                
          
            </span>
      <span class="slide9"> 
      <div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="portfolio2.php">
    <img src="portfolio4.png" alt="Northern Lights">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">portfolio4</div>
  <div class="portfolio-item-meta clearfix">
                           <h5><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></h5>
                     <p>PC solutions</p>
                        </div>
</div>


        
                    </span>
      <span class="slide9">  


<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="portfolio3.php">
    <img src="portfolio/portfolio5.png" alt="Mountains">
  </a>
  <div class="desc">portfolio6</div>
  <div class="portfolio-item-meta clearfix">
                           <h5><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio5</a></h5>
                     <p>PC solutions</p>
                        </div>
</div>
                
                    </span>
     <!-- <span class="slide9">slide9 5</span>-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="prev" class="control prev"></a>
  <a id="next" class="control next"></a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="js/script.js"></script>

<style>
@import url("css?family=Roboto");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.slide9r {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.wrapper9 {
  
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide9s {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: -400px;
  width: 10000px;
}

.slide9s.shifting {
  transition: left 0.2s ease-out;
}

.slide9 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFCF47;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(2),
.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(7) {
  /*background: #FFCF47;*/
    background:#7adcef00; 
}
.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(1),
.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(6) {
  /*background: #7ADCEF;*/
    background:#7adcef00;
}
.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(3) {
  /*background: #3CFF96;*/
    background:#7adcef00;
}
.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(4) {
  /*background: #a78df5;*/
    background:#7adcef00;
}
.slide9r.loaded .slide9:nth-child(5) {
  /*background: #ff8686;*/
    background:#7adcef00;
}

.control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: 2;
}

.prev,
.next {
  background-size: 22px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  background-image: url(ChevronLeft-512.png);
  left: -20px;
  display: none;
}

.next {
  background-image: url(ChevronRight-512.png);
  right: -20px;
  display: none;
}

.prev:active,
.next:active {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  
  
}
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
 
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}</style>



<script>
var slide9r = document.getElementById('slide9r'),
    slide9rItems = document.getElementById('slide9s'),
    prev = document.getElementById('prev'),
    next = document.getElementById('next');

function slide9(wrapper9, items, prev, next) {
  var posX1 = 0,
      posX2 = 0,
      posInitial,
      posFinal,
      threshold = 100,
      slide9s = items.getElementsByClassName('slide9'),
      slide9sLength = slide9s.length,
      slide9Size = items.getElementsByClassName('slide9')[0].offsetWidth,
      firstslide9 = slide9s[0],
      lastslide9 = slide9s[slide9sLength - 1],
      cloneFirst = firstslide9.cloneNode(true),
      cloneLast = lastslide9.cloneNode(true),
      index = 0,
      allowShift = true;
  
  // Clone first and last slide9
  items.appendChild(cloneFirst);
  items.insertBefore(cloneLast, firstslide9);
  wrapper9.classList.add('loaded');
  
  // Mouse events
  items.onmousedown = dragStart;
  
  // Touch events
  items.addEventListener('touchstart', dragStart);
  items.addEventListener('touchend', dragEnd);
  items.addEventListener('touchmove', dragAction);
  
  // Click events
  prev.addEventListener('click', function () { shiftslide9(-1) });
  next.addEventListener('click', function () { shiftslide9(1) });
  
  // Transition events
  items.addEventListener('transitionend', checkIndex);
  
  function dragStart (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    posInitial = items.offsetLeft;
    
    if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      posX1 = e.clientX;
      document.onmouseup = dragEnd;
      document.onmousemove = dragAction;
    }
  }

  function dragAction (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    
    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      posX2 = posX1 - e.touches[0].clientX;
      posX1 = e.touches[0].clientX;
    } else {
      posX2 = posX1 - e.clientX;
      posX1 = e.clientX;
    }
    items.style.left = (items.offsetLeft - posX2) + "px";
  }
  
  function dragEnd (e) {
    posFinal = items.offsetLeft;
    if (posFinal - posInitial < -threshold) {
      shiftslide9(1, 'drag');
    } else if (posFinal - posInitial > threshold) {
      shiftslide9(-1, 'drag');
    } else {
      items.style.left = (posInitial) + "px";
    }

    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
  
  function shiftslide9(dir, action) {
    items.classList.add('shifting');
    
    if (allowShift) {
      if (!action) { posInitial = items.offsetLeft; }

      if (dir == 1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial - slide9Size) + "px";
        index++;      
      } else if (dir == -1) {
        items.style.left = (posInitial + slide9Size) + "px";
        index--;      
      }
    };
    
    allowShift = false;
  }
    
  function checkIndex (){
    items.classList.remove('shifting');

    if (index == -1) {
      items.style.left = -(slide9sLength * slide9Size) + "px";
      index = slide9sLength - 1;
    }

    if (index == slide9sLength) {
      items.style.left = -(1 * slide9Size) + "px";
      index = 0;
    }
    
    allowShift = true;
  }
}

slide9(slide9r, slide9rItems, prev, next);
</script>
```

Tried clearfix in hopes of a div overlapping but didn't work, tried looking into eventhandlers for touch but i'm not on that level yet.
tried different carousels mechanisms , still didn't work.
tried outside of the carousel , it seemed to work, but than i lose the carousel functionality.
Would love someone to enlighten me , i want for any image in the carousel upon clicking for it to lead to another page within the href address on a mobile phone with a touch screen.
Thanks for the helpers !

Simpler example which causes the same issue:

```js
document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<a href="?123=2">
  <p>test</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Some questions:
1. any reason to not use the Bootstrap CDN instead of the Isolated one?
2. Did you tried using Slick or Swiper for your carousels? they both handle better the responsiveness for mobile

Comment: I used the isolated one for a different reason, but in this case, most of the site uses an older and outdated bootstrap and jquery, and I decided that I wanted to add all kinds of functionalities that are easier to handle with the latest bootstrap , but it would break the site so I isolated it to a few places, on this carousel the only thing I've used it on for the time being is a class that helps center the carousel within another div.  Using anything like slick or any other prebuilt framework for a carousel requires a newer jquery which this site doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a typo in your `<style>` tag. Change this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

to

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      /* text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 0.15em;
      font-size: 22px; */
    }
```

I commented those 3 lines, because it messes the styles, but you can uncomment them if you need them.
Also tested the fix on a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-violet-rzm3zp?file=/index.html&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675) too and it's working.

Furthermore, I added a `debounce` function for your `dragStart` so the drag will not interfere with your click event.

```js
...
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
 let timeoutId = null;
 return (...args) => {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
   callback.apply(null, args);
  }, wait);
 };
}
...
const debouncedDragStart = debounce(dragStart, 100);
...
items.addEventListener("touchstart", debouncedDragStart);
```

Comment: Thank you, this has indeed solved the issue with this carousel,  however in the end i have moved to a robust framework upon which i have built a carousel, had to learn all about eventlisteners and handlers, it seems that was the biggest issue by far , so you did good by adding the debounce for the drag ,  thanks again for your time to help me solve my issue! =]] I did learn a lot from this whole ordeal and with your input even more!

Comment: Happy to help @Menk and keep doing and learning!